# Where to find good manuals for Yamaha motorcycle?

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha, service-manual

Where can I find a manual for a specific yamaha motorcycle? If any of you knows or if you know where this question should be posted on this site let me know. I am aware that maybe this is not the best place for such a question.

Comment: What year, make, and model?

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski - xt 600e, year is 2003.

Comment: The "where" question seems off topic to me as a shopping question, better to ask "how" to find the manuals for old bikes / vehicles. The reason is that shopping advice can go stale very quickly, whereas information on how to track down manuals will work even after specific examples don't.

Comment: Plus you've not stated where you are... ebay and/or random motor spares shops are usually good places to look

Answer (score 2):

I recently ordered a manual for a very old Yamaha motorcycle. You can goto this website

http://www.yamahapubs.com/

You can use that website to lookup the part numbers for Yamaha motorcycles all the way back to 1971. You **do not** want the owner's manual. It tells you things like "take your motorcycle to the dealer to have the oil changed". You **do want** the service manual. You can use the part number for the service manual to search for it elsewhere.

For some reason, older Yamaha parts online generally have the best price at boating retailers. In my case I ordered from boats.net. I still haven't received the manual I ordered. Based on the date for delivery they gave me, they are probably actually printing one.

Pre 1971 is more of a challenge. I'm not sure if the service manuals still exist. Even if they do, the master copy is likely stored somewhere in Japan. Some websites such as http://www.ronayers.com have parts fiche going back to 1962 for Yamaha motorcycles.